# Concurrency without semaphore in Swift

Tags: swift, concurrency, queue

I'm trying to fix a concurrency race condition in my code, and I've been thinking about queues. Anybody can help me to understand why the following code doesn't work on iOS?

```
class Concurrency {
    private var privateStuff: Int  =  0
    var accessQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "read", qos: DispatchQoS.background, attributes: DispatchQueue.Attributes.concurrent, autoreleaseFrequency: DispatchQueue.AutoreleaseFrequency.workItem, target: nil)
    var writequeue = DispatchQueue(label: "write")
    var stuff: Int {
        get {
            var result: Int!
            accessQueue.sync {
                result = privateStuff
            }
            return result
        }
        set {
            accessQueue.suspend()
            writequeue.sync {
                    privateStuff = newValue
            }
            accessQueue.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

I still have a race condition, so Xcode says, if I run a high number of reader/writer on this.

Am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: as pointed out, suspension doesn't wait for current blocks to finish and this cause a race condition, so the solution below with .barrier works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like this solution fits your problem:

https://medium.com/@oyalhi/dispatch-barriers-in-swift-3-6c4a295215d6

The data race condition is given by the fact that you are using two different queues. There is nothing that does not block other threads to suspend `accessQueue` in the setter while another thread is asking for the getter of the property.

Like described in the article in the link there are few ways to solve this reader-writer problem.

My favourite is with barriers.

Also, I would be defensive with those queues setting them as `private let` instead of vars to avoid some brilliant colleague to pass mainQueue as accessQueue causing a thread lock on the main thread.

So the whole thing would look like that:

```
class Concurrency {
    private var privateStuff: String  =  
    private let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "read-write", qos: DispatchQoS.background, attributes: DispatchQueue.Attributes.concurrent, autoreleaseFrequency: DispatchQueue.AutoreleaseFrequency.workItem, target: nil)
    var stuff: String {
        get {
            var result: String!
            queue.sync {
                result = privateStuff
            }
            return result
        }
        set {
            queue.async(flags: .barrier) {
                    privateStuff = newValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry Giuseppe you clearly don't know how suspend()/resume() work, take a look here. TL;DR: call to suspend/resume has to be balanced. In addition I know how to solve concurrency issues, I just don't know why this doesn't work. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchobject/1452801-suspend

Comment: It's because you might suspend the queue while a read is currently running.

Comment: yeah it's probably because of the queued blocks before the suspension

Comment: Edited the answer about the suspend. I didn't know suspend/resume had to be balanced. sorry about that.

Comment: `queue.sync` returns the result of the closure. In this case, it just returns `()`, but you can instead have it return the value you want: `return queue.sync { return privateStuff }`

Comment: This is the correct approach. Using a dispatch barrier and a concurrent queue to allow concurrent reads greatly improves the read throughput, without sacrificing any safety.

Comment: Thumbs up for barrier solution. Will update my data model as well.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using following class to deal with race conditions:

```
public class Protected<Value> {

    private var queue = DispatchQueue(label: "me.gk.Lightning.Protected", attributes: .concurrent)
    private var _value: Value

    public var value: Value {
        get {
            return queue.sync { _value }
        }
        set {
            queue.async(flags: .barrier) { [weak self] in
                self?._value = newValue
            }
        }
    }

    public init(_ value: Value) {
        _value = value
    }

    public func read(_ block: (Value) -> Void) {
        queue.sync {
            block(_value)
        }
    }

    public func write(_ block: @escaping (inout Value) -> Void) {
        queue.async(flags: .barrier) { [weak self] in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
            block(&strongSelf._value)
        }
    }
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/gokselkoksal/Lightning

Usage:

```
var list = Protected(["item1"])

// Get value:
let items = list.value

// Set value:
list.value = ["item1", "item2"]

// Read block:
list.read { items in
    print(items)
}

// Write block:
list.write { items in
    items.append(...)
}
```

Comment: I know how to solve concurrency issues, I'd like to know why the queuing strategy doesn't work

Comment: `queue.sync`returns the result of the closure. In this case, it just returns `()`, but you can instead have it return the value you want: `return queue.sync { return privateStuff }`

Comment: You should be using a dispatch barrier. There's no reason for read operations to be synchronized, and doing so severely limited the throughput. Use a dispatch barrier, so that reads can be concurrent, with writes being synchronized.

Comment: @GökselKöksal Did you miss my first comment?

Comment: Edited again :) @Alexander